# Не могу подключить memcached. Выдаёт ошибку когда запускаю example.php

Tags: php, xampp, memcache

Следовала по http://ruphp.com/memcache-xampp-windows-7-8-10.html. Memcache  сервер скачала, установила. Memcache.dll  скачала, файл поместила в xampp \ php \ ext . Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Ошибка выходит следующая

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function memcache_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\memcached\example.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\memcached\example.php on line 3

Comment: в пхп.ини длл-ку не подключили

Comment: extension=php_memcache.dll [Memcache] memcache.allow_failover = 1 memcache.max_failover_attempts=20 memcache.chunk_size =8192 memcache.default_port = 11211 Подключила. memcache.dll вставила в папку php->ext. Не могу понять в чём  ошибка?

Comment: `phpinfo` посмотрите, что там закгружено а что нет. я не в курсе что вы там качали, мб разрядность не совпадает, например.